# How to Install a tex editor without texlive on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: texlive, editors, ubuntu

I installed texlive 2016 on my ubuntu 16.04 and everything works fine. Now when I try to install an editor (like kile, texmaker, texstudio, etc.) through  `apt-get install` I'm forced to install texlive packages from ubuntu, as if I didn't have texlive already... How can I manage to just install a tex editor without installing texlive ?

Comment: Could you please let us know the exact commands you are using to install the LaTeX GUI? Are you sure the texlive is already installed completely? What are the additional packages which you are *forced* to install?

Comment: `Apt` has an `equivs` package, which you can use to circumvent the Debian/Ubuntu package dependencies. See [Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian](https://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html) (scroll down to that heading).

Comment: You might also be using a package that's not on the standard `texlive` package. To download and install _all_ of texlive you'd do `apt-get install texlive-full`

Comment: @wolf_math That's exactly what the OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Masroor here is what I did : I downloaded `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`, then I did `sudo apt-get install perl-tk`, then `./install-tl -gui=perltk`. If I need to install additional packages I use `tlmgr -gui`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As jon suggested, you can create a texlive dummy package using equivs and install it. That would satisfy the dependency requirements for any package that needs texlive*.

As I see texstudio does not have a dependency on texlive. So, to prevent apt from pulling in the extra packages, you can try installing it thus:

```
apt-get --no-install-recommends install texstudio
```

Edit: Following crocefisso's observation, including install in the command.

Comment: I don't remember how I did it (months ago), but it definitely can be done. On Ubuntu 16.04 I have TeXLive 2016 in my home folder, obtained directly from TeXLive, not the Ubuntu distro. And, I have TeXworks, via the Ubuntu distro. As I recall, it required some trickery. So have faith, OP, and follow the instructions given in the answers.

Comment: @mas Thanks, it worked like a charm! It also works with texmaker and the other editors. You forgot `install` in your line : `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends <package>`

Comment: Oops. Nice catch. Glad it helped.

Comment: Great: this is still working on Ubuntu 20.04 in 2021!