# How to install texstudio without texlive on Fedora?

Tags: texlive, texstudio, linuxfedora

- OS: Fedora 37 Workstation
- Question: I want to install texstudio through `dnf install`, but it seems that I have to install a lot of **texlive dependencies** with it. I have installed **texlive 2022** before, and I don't want this extra distribution installation (which is not up-to-date and it is hard for me to manage several distributions of latex).
- Similar questions

  - [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355778/286140) might be helpful for `apt-get` tool in debian, but I don't know if there's similar ways in Fedora to skip all these dependencies and just install the package using `dnf` tool;
  - [this answer](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?321475-How-to-install-Texstudio-without-TeXlive-dependencies) gave the solution of download and install `.rpm` package, but when I tried this I found that it was still a must to install those texlive dependencies :( maybe the answer is too old to be helpful.

What's more, I found that there are similar situations for installing other TeX editors, such as `Kile` and `TeXmaker`. It's fine for `TeXworks`, but I think I need some functions that `TeXworks` does not have.

Appreciate for any possible solutions!

Comment: I have not used `rpm` package manager  for 20 years or so, but `--nodeps --nosuggest` seems promising. If you're afraid of making a mess, use `--test` and think twice before of remove this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Fran, I have tried and it seems to work for now!

I'm writing the process down for possible checks by others.

1. If you are using Ubuntu, just check the [official website](https://www.texstudio.org/#download) to add `PPA` and use `apt` or `apt-get` tools;
2. For now, I have not found a specific rpm download link from official website (maybe I happened to leave it out), but I found it [here](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=texstudio), so just go and get it.
3. Open your terminal and `cd` to the download `.rpm` path, and `sudo rpm -i ./texstudio-rpm-name.rpm --nodeps` will help you out.
4. The method just works for those who has installed one distribution of `TeXlive` just like me; or you can just install `TeXstudio` by `sudo dnf install texstudio` and it will automatically install texlive dependencies. I hope maybe in the future it will be okay to just let users select whether they are in need for a new texlive when installing :)